Why a minus sign is often put into the law of induction for an inductor
My question is only didactic:
I have been observing for a long time that students in particular always put a minus sign in front of the induction law:
u(t) = - L di(t)/dt
It is clear to me that there is a minus in Maxwell's equation for the law of induction. However, it is always argued that even with a self-inductance you have to add minus, since according to Lenz's rule the voltage must be opposite to an increase in the current.
But this only works if you have the reference arrows for U and I pointing in opposite directions, i.e. using a "active sign convention". I recently had a discussion with a student who stubbornly insisted that there had to be a minus here too:

So u = - L * di/dt would have to be written (which is clearly wrong). He wanted to explain to me, that there are in fact two different voltages: one I can measure and the other somehow "intrinsically" with opposite sign and both are cancelling each other...(?)...  I observed this argumentation not just once, but regularly and I want just to understand what people mean.
Is it, because they want to distinguish between voltage and EMF? Voltage I can measure directly, what is the benefit to mix it up with an old-fashioned concept EMF ? I have never needed this term in my life when analyzing circuits.
I also often notice that the inductance is artificially replaced by a voltage source that, when pointed in the same direction as i, has the value i=L*di/dt.
That's not wrong, but in my opinion it's completely unnecessary. In a circuit with a source voltage u0 and an ohmic resistance R, I won't replace the resistance first with a voltage source
u' = i * R
and then argue at the end u0-u'=0, which immediately leads back to i=u0/R. Here the same approach seems completely meaningless, but this is how it is taught again and again with inductors: "the inductor creates an opposite voltage source against increase of current". Doing the same for the resistor would sound ridiculous. Using the constitutive relation U=L*di/dt is completely sufficient and there is no need, to use the concept of a second voltage source built up by the inductor. This causes more confusion than benefit.
Why is this and where does it come from?

We in EE do not have a minus sign because of a passive sign convention. The symbolic voltage across an inductor is defined to be positive at the terminal where the symbolic current enters. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DutVZLUvPZc&t=120s

I know. But unfortunately in school books it is stated sometimes in a wrong way. I have seen images with both passive sign convention and the minus sign. Once I talked even to my daughter's  teacher, but is was hopeless to convince him, that this was wrong. I finally gave up. It seems, that he minus sign is somehow more a religious fact of physics teachers and kept from generation to generation without knowing the meaning. On university in the field of EE nobody uses the minus at all.

The physics community and the electrical engineering community do not always find the same things important, and so do not always see eye to eye.
In physics the \$\vec{E}\$ field is something fundamental. In electrical engineering, the quantity \$\Delta V\$ (or just "V") measured by a voltmeter, or by an oscilloscope, called by EE's simply "voltage", or potential difference, is of primary importance. It would be nice if
$$\Delta V = \int_{C:a\rightarrow b} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$$
but it is not, at least not in the case of inductors. The physicist will tell you, correctly, that the \$\vec{E}\$ field within a conductor is determined by the microscopic version of Ohm's Law.
$$\vec{J} = \sigma\vec{E}$$
Current density is equal to the conductivity of the conductor times the \$\vec{E}\$ field. Since the conductivity of copper wire is very high, the \$\vec{E}\$ field within the copper wire of an inductor is very small. We can often ignore it, and treat it as if the \$\vec{E}\$ field in the wires of an inductor is 0. But we can also use a voltmeter or oscilloscope and see that there is a \$\Delta V\$ across the inductor.
If you don't mind that the \$\vec{E}\$ field within the wires of an inductor is very small, and proportional to the current density within the inductor, then you can continue to use the EE's "V" or \$\Delta V\$. Everything will continue to work. The sign of \$\Delta V\$ will depend entirely on how you choose to annotate your circuit with arrows. However, now and again, you will meet someone trained in physics or by physicists, who doesn't really understand that the EE's \$\Delta V\$ is not the same as the physicist's \$\int_a^b\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}\$, who reasons that since
$$\nabla\times\vec{E} = \color{red}{-}\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$
that it must be the case that
$$V = \color{red}{-}LI'$$
In that case you can respond that
$$\Delta V \ne \int_{C:a\rightarrow b} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$$
doesn't mean for the EE that \$\Delta V\$ is undefined in the presence of a time-varying magnetic field, it means that the EE's \$\Delta V\$ is a different concept from \$\int_a^b \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}\$

If you want to get into the gory physics details, a physicist's equation for the EE's \$\Delta V\$ is
$$\Delta V=\int_a^b \left(\nabla\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{R^3}\frac{-\rho(r')}{\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{|r-r'|}d^3r'\right)\cdot d\vec{s}$$

From the comments:

The misunderstanding HERE was a difference of choosing reference arrows for voltage in Europe and US. Whether my original question has been answered I'm not sure.

I'm not convinced that it is a question of choosing different conventions for drawing arrows.
As I understand the circuit in following diagram (excluding the formula), as an increasing conventional current flows into the inductor from the top (per the arrow), a positive voltage will appear on in the voltmeter.

I can't understand how this might be interpreted in a different way. Thus, in my opinion, the formula in the diagram is just wrong, as has been stated in the original post.


What I wanted to express: I see no need to deal with any emf, the constitutive relation between voltage and current change U=L*di/dt is completely sufficient to solve any problem with inductors. What does ist help to extra define some emf?

The equation \$U=L\frac{dI}{dt}\$ is only valid for an ideal inductor. If we assume that the inductor coil has some resistance, then it is useful to divide the the terminal voltage into two parts, a magnetically induced part, proportional to \$L\frac{dI}{dt}\$ and a resistive voltage drop part proportional to \$IR\$. This separation is electrically important when the \$IR\$ voltage drop starts to become significant relative to the magnetically induced part. What the magnetically induced part is called is perhaps of less importance. If one creates a model of a real inductor consisting of a distinct ideal inductor and a distinct ideal resistor, and if the ideal inductor is given a name, then we have found a way to refer to the magnetically induced part without using the term "emf".

Even with your first equation it makes a difference if you integrate from A to B or vice versa. So a ΔV depends of the integration contour. ΔV can be Va-Vb in terms of potential or Vb-Va, depending which way you choose. It is not unique, we should better say Vab or Vba. The freedom is exactly the same freedom you have in connecting the plugs of a voltmeter. So, essentially, there is no difference between EE's picture ant that of a physicist. We don't go to the physics ins such detail, my question is at a level of school for 16 year old pupils, not for university.

The misunderstanding HERE was a difference of choosing reference arrows for voltage in Europe and US. Whether my original question has been answered I'm not sure.

16 year olds are getting their misinformation from books or teachers. The origin of the confusion lies in a physics/EE confusion, even if the 16 year old are unaware of it. Per physics, the back emf is negative relative to the applied voltage, because their difference is the IR voltage drop, which is typically quite small.

I'm starting to hate this discussion: This is my last trial to understand what you and others mean with back emf negative. This https://ucloud.univie.ac.at/index.php/s/SX4B7jN9tEqczKZ shows an inductor which is supplied with lets say 12V at t=0 by closing a switch. A Voltmeter connected like in the image would definitely measure a positive voltage - this voltage is related to the current by U=L*di/dt. My only remaining question: Where would you measure a negative voltage (the emf). You can define that emf is opposite to the voltage indicated by the meter - but what is the benefit of that?

What I wanted to express: I see no need to deal with any emf, the constitutive relation between voltage and current change U=L*di/dt is completely sufficient to solve any problem with inductors. What does ist help to extra define some emf?

The difference between supplied voltage across an inductor and induced voltage due to \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ is the sign.
It's as simple as that.

If you apply a voltage (V) across an inductor, current rises positively at a rate of V/L (no negatives involved)
If instead you use a 1:1 transformer, you still get the same \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ in the primary but the secondary induced voltage is in an opposing direction to the primary applied voltage V

So, if you want to talk about the induced voltage in an inductor (opposing the supply voltage V) then you would use a minus sign but, if you are just using the formula for determining rate of change of current you don't use a minus sign.
Just to be clear about what I mean when I say that the induced voltage is in an opposing direction to the applied voltage V; I mean it exactly like the voltage developed across a resistor has the opposite sign to the applied voltage.

it depends on which reference arrows are used to decide if a voltage is negative or positive. A voltage on an inductor per se (without defining a reference system) is meaningless with regard to a sign. What you mean with induced voltage is nothing else but L di/dt. It is "ooposite in the sense, that all voltages must sum up to zero, but has still a plus sign, when the passive reference system is used, not a minus.

I don't particularly like using reference arrows on this site. In the UK and America the arrow head signifies the more positive voltage but, in some parts of Europe (certainly in Germany) the arrow head signifies the direction of the electric field produced (the exact opposite) @MichaelW || Not sure if you are asking me something in your comment but what you did say doesn't strike me as being related to the topic in question.

My comment was about the sign of the induced voltage. It is clear, that an ideal inductor can be modelled like this: https://ucloud.univie.ac.at/index.php/s/FWQBJjidR3yc8nm But where is a voltage with minus sign? This would be the case, when it is measured vice versa, as opposed to the image. But what would be the benefit of doing so? The induced voltage and the applied voltage are the same, when using the same reference system. What else? The only question is, why some people think, there is a minus sign. It is clearly wrong.

Do your arrows represent field values i.e. are you using European convention (as opposed to UK/American convention)? This is what I was trying to explain in my earlier comment. Anyway, for an inductor I find it pointless to talk about induced EMF. I don't see that it brings anything useful to the table and, it appears that you might think the same @MichaelW || Aha you are from Austria so your arrows represent field values!!

I was not aware that US/American convention uses arrows from - to +.  In this case the minus sign is ok, but still it means that the upper part of the inductor has higher electric potential than the bottom part. I used European convention for my whole life and to be honest, I'm surprised of having overseen the difference over decades. Now I understand, why people insist on the minus with regard to my picture. Instead of the arrows I should have used + and -. So the correct picture would be https://ucloud.univie.ac.at/index.php/s/dijPj23LJPcyeE4

I believe everyone should be happy with + and - representing something meaningful. I was not aware EU countries used the arrow to represent field quantities until recently either. I bet there's been many an argument on this misunderstanding in the past!! I think why tutors teach about back-emf in an inductor is (more or less) because it gives an introduction to the concept when it comes to studying transformers. There it is very important but, in inductors, "back-emf" is of no use at all as far as I can see.

At university we were taught to always draw arrows in circuits before starting any analysis - without exceptions. A voltage result without a corresponding arrow was assessed as meaningless. In the U.S. they apparently use + and –, which amounts to the same thing.

@MichaelW as I said in my 1st comment, it's not related to the sign in the formula.

Your example with resistor is different than with inductor or capacitor.
If you connect an inductor to a 12V battery, there will be always 12V over the inductor, externally.
At the moment you connect it, the current starts to rise, from zero to upwards.
But because there is inductance that tries to resist the current from changing, there must be an "internal" voltage supply that tries to counter the supply you connected externally.
As the current is zero when you connect the 12V battery, it means that there is now a -12V from the induction that will try to resist the current from changing.
When the current through inductor has reached the point that it does not change, the di/dt part is zero so the "internal" supply from the induction is zero, and there will be the external 12V you applied over the inductor, which will at that point have just the coil resistance setting the DC current.
So to recap, at the moment you connect the inductor with coil resistance to 12V battery, there is no current but 12V externally over inductor, which means at zero current there is 0V over resistor so something inside the inductor must counter the 12V from having an effect.
After enough time passes, there will be 12V over the resistance and nothing to counter the externally applied 12V.

Yes, but you get the same result, by just knowing that the constitutive relation between u  und i is just given by u=L*di/dt. The sum of voltages in the circuit must be zero, so u0=i*R+L di/dt . This equation is completely sufficient and gives the same result. What is the benefit of putting a virtual voltage source in? [Edited by a moderator so that the * (asterisk) characters appear as intended.]

@MichaelW No you don't, unless you are looking at some special case where it happens to be true. Imagine a circuit where 10V battery, inductor and 10A load. If 10A flows, and I suddenly reduce th battery to 9V, the inductor will try to keep 10A flowing so it will try to boost the 9V battery to 10V for the load, while current will be slowly dropping from 10A towards 9A. Clearly there is 1V positive voltage change over the inductor while di/dt is negative.

I understand what you mean, but I do not need a separate voltage source, to model this behavior: Knowing, that on the(ideal) inductor I have u=L*di/dt I can write immediately (!) 9V=i(t)*R + L di(t)/dt with the initial condition i(0)=10A. This gives (with R=1 Ohm) rise to the exponential decay i(t) = 9A + 1A*exp(-t*R/L): i(0)=10A, i(∞)=9A. There is not one second where I need to consider an "artificial voltage source" to solve the problem. Don't understand me wrong: It can be solved in your way, but it is mathematically completely the same. Where is the benefit? [Edited by a mod as above.]

and also the 1V voltage change on the inductor arises naturally by 9V=i(t)*R + L di(t)/dt , because 9V=10V + L di(t)/dt. So  L di(t)/dt=-1V. No need to model this as separate voltage source. I used to model networks for over 40 years, but never did it in such way. The constitutive equations are enough and this was also the way I learned it long ago.

There is no wrong and right way for this. There are more than one way of looking at this, all correct depending on which point of view to take to have something done. You might use simplest way you can in EE, or you may want to use the absolutely most correct way for your field if you happen to be a theoretical physics type of person writing a paper to a journal. It does not change the result of calculations. It's just how precisely you want to model how an inductor works. For writing equations, you must be consistent which way currents and voltages work to.

But we agree, that the equation in my image is wrong when the passive sign convention is used - right? I have seen this in a school book and was really deeply surprised.

@MichaelW It is hard to figure out what your picture stands for. Inductor with externally applied voltage, or induced voltage, is the current steady, rising or falling. The fact is, if you externally apply 12V to a coil, there must be internally -12V induced inside it, as the current starts to rise from zero over the resistance so the voltage of the resistor must start from zero. You can't simulate that without internally induced current being negative when current rises i.e. di/dt is positive.

"there must be internally -12V induced": -12V against WHAT reference terminal: I updated my picture with a voltmeter.
When current I increases it would definitely measure a positive voltage U. Therefore the minus sign is wrong. If U is a positive applied voltage, the measured voltage would of course be the same, also POSITIVE , while I increases. So again, there is a plus in the equation. It doesn't matter, whether U is applied or not. There is a constitutive relation between I and U. The only question I have: where exactly do you identify a negative voltage?
